# Invoking express-validation functions as separate statements instead of using comma separated invocation is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express, sanitization

```
module.exports.register = function(req,res,next){

    body('fname').isLength({ min: 3, max:20 }).withMessage('First name must have minimum 3 chars and maximum 20 chars.')
    .isAlpha().withMessage('First name has non-alphabetic characters.');

    body('email').trim().isEmail().withMessage('Not in the email format');

    sanitizeBody('fname').trim().escape();

    sanitizeBody('email').trim().escape();

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        sendResponse(res,{status: 422 ,body:errors});
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
}
```

This piece of code executes through but express-validator doesn't seem to perform its functionality.

Instead, the below code works fine. But I suppose that in both cases it should work.

```
module.exports.register = [

    body('fname').isLength({ min: 3, max:20 }).withMessage('First name must have minimum 3 chars and maximum 20 chars.')
    .isAlpha().withMessage('First name has non-alphabetic characters.'),

    body('email').trim().isEmail().withMessage('Not in the email format'),

    sanitizeBody('fname').trim().escape(),

    sanitizeBody('email').trim().escape(),

    (req, res, next) => {

        const errors = validationResult(req);

        if(!errors.isEmpty()){
            sendResponse(res,{status: 422 ,body:errors});
        }
        else{
            next();
        }
    } 
]
```

I cannot find anything relevant to my query in the doc.
Any help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `express-validation` "statements" are essentially express middleware functions. This means that each of them ***returns*** a function with the signature `function(req, res, next)`. These functions are meant to be called by the express API.

What happens in your first example, is that every statement just returns a function that doesn't actually get called. Your first example is equivalent to this:

```
module.exports.register = function(req,res,next){

    function(req,res,next) {...}
    function(req,res,next) {...}
    function(req,res,next) {...}
    function(req,res,next) {...}

    const errors = validationResult(req);
    if(!errors.isEmpty()){
        sendResponse(res,{status: 422 ,body:errors});
    }
    else{
        next();
    }
}
```

In theory you could reformat your first example and make it work, but you would probably end in callback hell and I wouldn't advise it. Something among these lines:

```
module.exports.register = function(req,res,next){
    (body('fname').isLength({ min: 3, max:20 }).withMessage('First name must have minimum 3 chars and maximum 20 chars.').isAlpha().withMessage('First name has non-alphabetic characters.')) (req, res, 
      (body('email').trim().isEmail().withMessage('Not in the email format')) (req, res,  
          (sanitizeBody('fname').trim().escape()) (req, res, 
              (sanitizeBody('email').trim().escape()) (req, res, function(req, res, next) {

                 const errors = validationResult(req);

                   if(!errors.isEmpty()){
                     sendResponse(res,{status: 422 ,body:errors});
                   }
                   else{
                     next();
                   }
                })))));
}
```

Don't use this code, it's just an example of how ugly things could get. Use the array as in your second example.